# Convert XML column to row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have table combine with XML format for store multi value data. sample like this

| ID | NAME | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `<multi><m>BALANCE</m><m>INTEREST</m><m>FEE</m></multi>` | `<multi><m>1000</m><m>100</m><m>10</m></multi>` |
| 2 | `<multi><m>BALANCE</m><m>INTEREST</m><m>FEE</m></multi>` | `<multi><m>2000</m><m>200</m><m>20</m></multi>` |
| 3 | `<multi><m>BALANCE</m><m>INTEREST</m><m>FEE</m></multi>` | `<multi><m>3000</m><m>300</m><m>30</m></multi>` |
| 4 | `<multi><m>BALANCE</m><m>INTEREST</m><m>FEE</m></multi>` | `<multi><m>4000</m><m>400</m><m>40</m></multi>` |
| 5 | `<multi><m>BALANCE</m><m>INTEREST</m><m>FEE</m></multi>` | `<multi><m>5000</m><m>500</m><m>50</m></multi>` |

I need to convert this XML to row, repeat by ID

| ID | NAME | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BALANCE | 1000 |
| 1 | INTEREST | 100 |
| 1 | FEE | 10 |
| 2 | BALANCE | 2000 |
| 2 | INTEREST | 200 |
| 2 | FEE | 20 |
| 3 | BALANCE | 3000 |
| 3 | INTEREST | 300 |
| 3 | FEE | 30 |
| 4 | BALANCE | 4000 |
| 4 | INTEREST | 400 |
| 4 | FEE | 40 |
| 5 | BALANCE | 5000 |
| 5 | INTEREST | 500 |
| 5 | FEE | 50 |

How to achieve this query in SQL Server?

I have tried using this code:

```sql
SELECT  
    p.ID, 
    NAME = Name.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'), 
    AMOUNT = Amount.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')
FROM 
    PRODUCTS p 
CROSS APPLY 
    NAME.nodes('/multi/m') AS tag (Name)
CROSS APPLY 
    AMOUNT.nodes('/multi/m') AS tag2 (Amount)
```

The result is not what I expected because NAME will repeat for every AMOUNT

Comment: Without seeing the actual XML how can we advise? For example, where does `multi/m` come from, and why would you shred the same nodes twice?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're wanting to select matching pairs of `m` XML nodes between the NAME and AMOUNT columns. You could do this by making use of the [`sql:column()` XQuery function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column) in conjunction with some index values to select them by their child index under, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  p.ID,
  NAME = tag.Name.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)') ,
  AMOUNT = tag2.Amount.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')
FROM PRODUCTS p
cross apply (values (1), (2), (3) ) L (LinkingIndex)
cross apply NAME.nodes('(/multi/m)[sql:column("LinkingIndex")]') AS tag ( Name )
cross apply AMOUNT.nodes('(/multi/m)[sql:column("LinkingIndex")]') AS tag2 ( Amount );
```

Which yields the result...

| ID | NAME | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BALANCE | 1000 |
| 1 | INTEREST | 100 |
| 1 | FEE | 10 |
| 2 | BALANCE | 2000 |
| 2 | INTEREST | 200 |
| 2 | FEE | 20 |
| 3 | BALANCE | 3000 |
| 3 | INTEREST | 300 |
| 3 | FEE | 30 |
| 4 | BALANCE | 4000 |
| 4 | INTEREST | 400 |
| 4 | FEE | 40 |
| 5 | BALANCE | 5000 |
| 5 | INTEREST | 500 |
| 5 | FEE | 50 |